# nginx location regex multiple elements

Tags: regex, nginx

I want to create one location regex for an endpoint that I currently serve using the following four rules.

```
location ~* ^/api/(?<version>.*)/(?<service>.*)(/.*/.*/.*/.*)$ {
...
}

location ~* ^/api/(?<version>.*)/(?<service>.*)(/.*/.*/.*)$ {
...
}

location ~* ^/api/(?<version>.*)/(?<service>.*)(/.*/.*)$ {
...
}

location ~* ^/api/(?<version>.*)/(?<service>.*)(/.*)$ {
...
}
```

That allow an access to my APIs using the following routes:

```
https://myapp.mydomain.com/api/v1/anyservice/foo
https://myapp.mydomain.com/api/v2/anyservice/foo/bar
https://myapp.mydomain.com/api/v1/anotherservice/foo/bar/thingy
https://myapp.mydomain.com/api/v1/anotherservice/foo/bar/thingy/owl
```

I have tried many solutions. For example:

```
location ~* "^/api/(?<version>.*)/(?<service>.*)(/.*){1,4}$" {
...
}
```

or

```
location ~* "^/api/(?<version>.*)/(?<service>.*)(/.*)*$" {
...
}
```

None of the solution I've tried has worked. Any idea ?

Comment: Could you make an example

Comment: The content has been edited with four examples or urls.

Comment: Does the Version (v1) or the service (anyservice) change ?

Comment: yes, it's a multi-version micro-services environment. The values of **version** and **service** are also injected into the header of the requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex to achive your goal:

```
/api/(?<version>[^/]+)/(?<service>[^/]+)(?:/[^/]+){1,4}$
```

You must set the `'multiline'` option if your text contains more than one line (like in exmaple above).

The regex starts matching `'/api/`' (Note the `'^`' symbol you had is removed, since it's not start of line).

Then it creates a named Group `'version'` that matches any characters `not being a slash`, then a `slash` and a new named Group `'service`. Again it matches any character `not being a slash`.

Then it creates a non capturing Group, matching a `slash` followed by any characters `not being a slash`. This Group is matched `from 1 to 4 times`.

**Edit**:

To match the `path` in a Group, I have changed to include a named Group called `'path'`:

```
/api/(?<version>[^/]+)/(?<service>[^/]+)(?<path>(?:/[^/]+){1,4})$
```

Now you get the path in the `'path'` Group.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly ! Note that you have to put some the regex between quotes because of **{**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understood your question correctly but this RegEx  might solve it.

```
.*\/api\/(v\d)\/(.+service)(\/.+\/?)*
```

It matches every given example.

In `Group 1` it captures the `Version`.

In `Group 2` it captures the `Service`.

In `Group 3` it captures the `/foo`.